# API Design Best Practice: Is it good idea to structure an SQL SELECT query as json-like using json_build_object

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am developing a web-based application that implements the following:

1. PostgreSQL RDBMS non-ORM database
2. Django Rest Framework for designing and handling data serializers and API requests in the backend
3. for GET methods, design the SQL SELECT query to have a json-like structure
   using json_build_object

**IN DATABASE**

```
person(personid, fullname, cityid)
city(cityid, cityname, countryid)
country(countryid, countryname)
```

**IN SERIALIZER**

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
 id=serializers.IntegerField()
 name=serializers.CharField()

class CitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
 id=IntegerField()
 name=CharField()
 country=CountrySerializer()

class PersonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
 id=IntegerField()
 person=CharField()
 city=CitySerializer()
```

**IN API VIEW**

```
from .custom_utils import raw_sql_select

class APIView_Person(generics.GenericAPIView):
  serializer_class = PersonSerializer
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
  def get_queryset(self):
   query=("""
    SELECT
     p.personid as id,
     p.fullname as person,
     json_build_object(
      'id',ct.cityid,
      'name',ct.cityname,
      'country',json_build_object(
        'id',cntry.countryid,
        'name',cntry.countryname
       )
     ) AS city
     FROM persons p
     JOIN city ct ON ct.cityid=p.cityid
     JOIN country cntry ON cntry.countryid=ct.countryid
   """)
   return raw_sql_select(query, "db_connection")

  def get(self, request):
   rows = [
    {
      "id": col.id,
      "person": col.person,
      "city": col.city
    } for col in self.get_queryset()[1]
   ]
   results = PersonSerializer(rows, many=True).data
   return Response(results or [])
```

**IN FRONTEND**

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
 personList: []
})

useEffect(()=>{
  fetch('/api/persons/', {method: 'GET', headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(rows=>setState(states=>({...states,personList:rows})))
}, [])

return(
 <>
  <Typography variant="body1" component="p">{state.person}</Typography>
  <Typography variant="caption" component="p" color="textSecondary">{state.city}, {state.city.country} 
  </Typography>
 </>
)
```

This is how my API is currently designed.

1. Why am I using raw sql query? Because I am using a database that is not created within my Django app so I do not have models for those to implement Django's ORM.
2. Why is my query structured json-like? Because I am using a serializer that does not rely on a model and does not extend the ModelSerializer class.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good, acceptable approach?
2. Will such design pose a future problem in terms of maintainability in case a database structure was changed?
3. If I change the CountrySerializer() from name=CharField() to country_name=CharField() then consequently change my API backend logic to return the response's object key from 'name' to 'country_name', and I have 20 frontend modules that reference to the old 'name' object key - then presumably I'd have to edit those 20 frontend modules to change 'name' reference to 'country_name'. ***Is this type of maintenance inevitable and considered a common, possible encounter in RESTFul API?***

Comment: If you have an existing table, you could write your model to match that existing structure, no…?

Comment: Mmm that would be possible. However, it is not a legacy database and the DB admin makes changes to it from time to time. Making changes to my mirror model when the DB admin makes changes to the existing structure would be redundant. The DB is currently being polished and is primarily used by another application. The app I am working on needs the records from that database. I am also not sure but I think the API should have been designed and served from within the primary app that is using it and not from my application.

Comment: If the table is changing occasionally anyway, then you may or may not need to adjust your code to it anyway, regardless of whether you do so using models or raw SQL.

Comment: So if the DB admin removes the `city` column from `person` table and 20 frontend modules would be affected, for sure I would have to adjust both my backend and frontend codes, right. Such case is pretty normal in RESTFul APIs right?

Comment: Sure. If you use Django's models for that, the change is usually more self-contained than needing to adjust raw SQL queries. That depends on how flexible you're writing your code obviously. Either way, nothing prevents your use of Django models here, so this entire question may be moot…?